# Confusion at orderliness while using unordered list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I think my question is the simplest question on this site. Nevertheless i couldn't solve it.

Now, i have a html like bottom. Elements have to be shown side by side. However output is like in picture below. Also, I did not get where the underscore come up from.
  [image: confused order]
How can i do what i want?

```
        <div class="ilgiliclass">
    <?php
                echo '<ul>';
                if(...)
                {
                    foreach(...)
                    {
                        if(...)
                        {
     ?>

                                <li>
                                    <img src="img/arrow.gif">
                                    <div class="si">
                                        <a href="...">...</a> 
                                    </div>                                                             
                                    -
                                    <div class="so">
                                        <a href="...">...</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                </li>

    <?php        
                        }
                    }  
                }  
    ?>
            </ul>
```

Comment: does your `<a>` hyperlinks actually wrap lines? if so, that's where the underscore is coming from... keep the links tight around your content.

Comment: Rendered HTML and CSS output only please. This is a question of looks, we don't care about the PHP.

Comment: Here is my rendered output:
http://www.olmasigereken.com/demo/?view=listen&artist=ibrahim+ferrer&track=dos+gardenias
I want to put everything on correct order which is _image artist - track twitter and facebook links_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a dash in your markup between the `si` and `so` elements. I imagine that's the 'underscore' you are talking about. Both `.si` and `.so` could be set to `display:inline;`, which should put everything on one line.

JS Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TYsN6/

Comment: thank you for your answer. When i apply your answer result looks like: http://i46.tinypic.com/hwho45.jpg This is not i want. The order is wrong.

Comment: When I do it locally I get: image text1 - text2. My guess is that you have some CSS that you aren't providing us. http://jsfiddle.net/TYsN6/

Comment: Friends, my problem is still unsolved. i post a link about what i am talking.
http://www.olmasigereken.com/demo/?view=listen&artist=ibrahim+ferrer&track=dos+gardenias
I want to put everything at correct order which is _image artist - track twitter and facebook links_.

Comment: You have floats on your anchors. Removing `float:left;` from 
`.ikinciSol ul li a` fixes the issue.